# How do I append a string to a char?

Tags: c++

How do I append a string to a char?
      strcat(TotalRam,str);
is what i got but it does not support strings

Comment: I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, please respect that people are at different places in their pursuit of mastery in programming at different points in their lives.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `std::string` from a `char` and `std::string` object?  In other words, are you trying to combine a `std::string` of length one with some other arbitrary string?

Comment: @David Gladfelter all with good humour. See quotes by Charles Babbage.  ;)

Comment: @David: Also note that the esteemed Lord of Hacking here has a very special history...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::String has a function called c_str(), that gives you a constant pointer to the internal c string, you can use that with c functions. (but make a copy first)

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` on strings:

```
std::string newstring = std::string(TotalRam) + str;
```

If you want it as a `char[]` instead, you need to allocated memory on the heap or stack first.  After that, `strcat` or `sprintf` are possible options.

Answer (score 2):

You can't append a string to a char, you can only append a string to a string (or a char* if using the C string functions).  In your example, you'll have to copy (the char) TotalRam into a string of some sort, either a C++ std::string, or make a char[2] to hold it and the required terminating NULL character.  Then you can either use the C++ string with C++ functions or the char[2] with strcat and friends.

Answer (score 0):

for performance, do this:

```
char ministring[2] = {0,0};
// use ministring[0] as your char, fill it in however you like
strcat(ministring,str);
```

The char array is stack-allocated so it is extremely fast, and the second char with the value of zero acts as a string terminator so that functions like strcat will treat it as a 'c' string.

Comment: Almost exactly what I put +1 for trying

Comment: I think you've got your parameters backwards on the strcat.  If you meant it to be the way you have it written, then this will result in stack corruption because str will be appended to your stack allocated ministring.  if str is long enough, this will corrupt other values below ministring on the stack.  (Including the return address pointer, resulting in a buffer overflow attach that could easily be used for remote code execution.)

Comment: My bad, I haven't used c string functions in quite some time.